# MySQL Match Against & Like

Tags: mysql, match, match-against

I've created a fulltext index this way:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX filter_index
ON posts (filter)
```

And my code for searching is currently this:

```
SELECT * FROM posts
WHERE MATCH(filter) AGAINST (?)
```

The query performs Ok, and in my table I have the following structure.

```
ID | name   | from           | filter
 1   John     Paris - France | John Paris France
 2   Carey    Paris - France | Carey Paris France
 3   Maria    France - Vion  | Maria France Vion
 4   Alfredo  US New York    | Alfredo US New York
 5   JohnD    Colombia       | JohnD Colombia
```

If I query the following:

```
SELECT * FROM posts
    WHERE MATCH(filter) AGAINST ('France Vion')
```

This will get me first the results:
`John Paris France & Carey Paris France` and only after that the `Maria France Vion`.

Shouldn't this be different? First the `Maria France Vion` and only after that the others results?

How can I optimize this operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT *, MATCH(filter) AGAINST('France Vion' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as relevance
FROM posts_locale 
WHERE MATCH(filter) AGAINST('France Vion' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

Also if you want to search two different fields and give priority. Like search `from` and `filter` but give higher priority to `from` filed

```
SELECT *, 
MATCH(filter) AGAINST('France Vion' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as relevance,
MATCH(`from`) AGAINST('France Vion' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as relevance_from
FROM posts 
WHERE MATCH(`from`, filter) AGAINST('France Vion' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY (relevance_from * 2) + relevance DESC
```

Number two (2) in here `ORDER BY (relevance_from * 2) + relevance DESC` doubles the priority. In some cases this can be high. You may try something like `1.5` or lower

Comment: Since that you posted it with tags, I accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to "ask" for the score as well.

Try this:

```
SELECT    *, MATCH(filter) AGAINST('{keyword}') as Relevance 
FROM      posts 
WHERE     MATCH(filter) AGAINST('{keyword}' 
ORDER BY  Relevance DESC
```